# How to get the current position for non gps phone in nokia j2me?

Tags: java, java-me, geolocation, gps, midlet

I  want to retrieve the latitude and longitude in j2me for non gps nokia mobile. when i googled,i found that we can get the current location based on the cellid, but it's not working properly, kindly provide me a solution for this...

Comment: What did you try with CellID? Any code?

Comment: i tried this 1)http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Finding_position_in_Java_ME 2)http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Using_a_JSR-179_Location_Provider_and_displaying_the_result_on_a_Map 3)http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Best_practises_for_listening_to_location_updates_with_Java_ME

Comment: @PrasanthS recursion doesn't help here, I guess. Please correct your link in your comment.

Comment: Lol, that leads right back here.

Comment: Check software from this list : http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Software/J2ME see if any of them work on non GPS j2me. When u find one working decompile it.